# FocusOut when changing language

Tags: c++, qt, events

I've installed `eventFilter` for my widget on the form, here is the code:

```
te_Execute->installEventFilter(&w);
```

In `w.eventFilter` i'm checking if event is `focusOut` and exit if it is:

```
bool FastExecute::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut && object == (QComboBox*) gui["te_Execute"])
        exit(0);
    return false;
}
```

But when i'm changing my language (Ctrl+Shift) my app is closing, because `focusOut` event works. Why is that happening?

You can see full code on `github.com`: https://github.com/EfogDev/FastExecute

Thanks!

Comment: Your app is closing because you are calling `exit` when the combo box loses focus. The program appears to be doing _exactly_ what you've told it to do.

Comment: Why `ComboBox` is losing focus when i'm changing language?

Comment: Well does a window pop up when you change the language?

Comment: Of course, no. Thats why i wrote here. No visual effects at all.

Comment: `exit(0)` is a very bad way of leaving the Qt event loop. Please use `qApp->quit()` or something similar.

Comment: Which window manager are you using?

Comment: Unity on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: @Efog: what exactly is a surprise in here? If you lose the focus like that and if you handle that as exit, what is the problem? The window manager will take the focus away to changing your language, I believe.

Comment: So, how i can catch deactivate event then? All Qt events such as WindowDeactivate, WindowStateChanged are working when i'm changing language.